# Deselect a selected area of imagemap when hovering over the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, imagemapster

I have succesfully created an imagemap using ImageMapster.js, I run into one issue though. My client wants one area to be selected when the page loads and when the user hovers over the map that the selected area becomes deselected and behaves like the rest of the areas. However I can't seem to work it out how to achieve this. The selected area stays selected all the time. This is my initial code:

```
$('#mpMap').mapster({
map: $('#mpMap'),
mapKey: 'data-key',
set: true,
fillOpacity: .6,
fillColor: 'faf7db',
stroke: true,
strokeColor:'faf7db',
strokeWidth: 1,
scaleMap: true,
clickNavigate: true,
isSelectable: false,
areas:  [{
key: "area_1", 
selected: true,
}],
});
```

I am aware that using selected: true makes the area selected all the time, but it is the only function I could find that selects the area directly after pageload. I am trying to figure out how I can create a new state that will reset all initial settings on mouseover. I tried several things (modifying the Beatles demo code for example) but I can't get the area_1 to deselect on mousover.

I hope somebody can help me or tell me if it is possible at all with this script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your point but you can try following workaround. Default of imagemapster behavior, when you select an area, that area is marked as selected (default it has stroke and fill blur background). I just change the option render_select to make its visual like normal situation

```
$("#fixImage").mapster({

            render_select: {
                stroke: false,
                fill: false
            },

            ...

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Telvin, I am not sure if this will work as I need the area to be visually selected when entering the page, but stop appearing selected when the user starts hovering over the entire image. I will try and see if this helps though.